# Yii Url Parameter Automatically placed in URL's

Tags: php, yii

Hello (sorry for my english...)

I got an aplication in Yii. I choose diffrent databases depending on `$_GET['project']`. My urls looks like i`ndex.php?r=controler/action&project=MyProject`.

But i have to add `&project=..` to every single link on my site, how can i make Yii do it automatically?

Comment: &project=-- blank or what ??

Comment: @Ninad Its `&project` not `$project`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`CUrlManager::createUrl()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#createUrl-detail) (or one of the other `createUrl()` variants) to create your links, you could override it in your own custom `UrlManager`:

```
class UrlManager extends CUrlManager {
  public function createUrl($route, $params=array(), $ampersand='&') {
    isset($params['project']) || $params['project'] = 'MyProject';
    return parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);
  }
}
```

Then in your config be sure to use your own custom `UrlManager` class:

```
return array(
  ...

  'components' => array(
    'urlManager' => array(
      'class' => 'UrlManager',
    ),
  ),

  ...
);
```